# Does it make sense to use JPA's 2.0 @Inheritance annotation to a subclass?

Tags: java, persistence, jpa-2.0

I was wondering if it makes any sense (or even if it is correct) to annotate every class of a hierarchy with @Inheritance. For example, suppose we have the following simple hierarchy:

```
public class A { ... }
public class B extends A { ... }
public class C extends A { ... }
```

In order to persist objects of these classes, we would annotate class A as follows:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A { ... }
```

My question is, do we need to add the @Inheritance annotation to class B and C also? As the Javadoc says **"It is specified on the entity class that is the root of the entity class hierarchy."** so my potential answer would be, no! But if we do annotate them, does this have any meaning at all, or is it completely ignored?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Inheritance annotation to subclasses if you need to use not default InheritanceType.

As you know, there is 3 InheritanceTypes supported. Table per class hierarchy, Table per subclass and Table per concrete class.
InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE is used by default, and all of your parent class and subclasses objects will be placed in one table.

If you want to use InheritanceType.JOINED or InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS, you need to add @Inheritance annotation.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit. I have already annotated the base class with InheritanceType.JOINED. My question is this: is it valid/legal/meaningful to also annotate a subclass and maybe choose another InheritanceType (e.g. InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)?

Comment: If you want to use JOINED for Subclass1 and TABLE_PER_CLASS for Subclass2, you should add annotations for each subclass. Also, it is not necessary to add annotation to superclass.

If you add annotation for superclass, then all subclasses without annotation should use it.

Comment: So if I annotate class A with JOINED, leave class B as is and annotate class C with TABLE_PER_CLASS, according to what you say I should have:

Comment: Class B would have InheritanceType.JOINED and class C would have InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS

Comment: Yes but from what I understand this would have no effect for the persistence of the three classes (all of them would be persisted according to JOINED), because when you annotate the subclass with a different strategy, this strategy will be followed for the subhierarchy rooted at that subclass but not the subclass itself. Isn't that how it works?

Comment: No. If you add annotation to a subclass, it should take effect to a subclass and subhierarchy rooted at that subclass.